# Encoding problems when copy pasting from a remote desktop session

Tags: remote-desktop, copy-paste, character-encoding

I connect to a distant machine to copy some arabic text to my machine.

When connecting through teamviewer, I get the text nice and clean when pasted on my machine, like this :

> تدخر جهدا في سبيك توفير  اكحماية ككصحفيين, وذكك بعد أن هددت حركة
>   طاكبان اكمتمردة بشن هجوم عكى مقر قناتين  تكفزيونيتين في كابوك واسته

When connecting through RDP, I get this instead

> ÑæãÇ 27 ÓÈÊãÈÑ 2017 (æÇÌ)- ÍÞÞ äÇÏí äÇÈæßí ÇßÅíØÇßí ÇäÊÕÇÑÇ åÇãÇ Úßì
>   ÖíÝå   ÝíäæÑÏ ÑæÊÑÏÇã ÇßåæßäÏí (3-1) Ýí ÇßßÞÇÁ ÇßÐí ÌãÚåãÇ ãÓÇÁ ÇãÓ
>   ÇßËßÇËÇÁ Úßì   ãßÚÈ (ÓÇä ÈÇæßæ) Ýí ÅØÇÑ ÇßÌæßÉ ÇßËÇäíÉ ãä ÇßãÌãæÚÉ
>   ÇßÓÇÏÓÉ ßßÃÓ ÑÇÈØÉ   ÃÈØÇß ÃæÑæÈÇ ßßÑÉ ÇßÞÏã

Any tip on how to troubleshoot this ?

I am copying text from a third party application on the remote server to notepad on the local machine.

Comment: RDP shares the host clipboard, and notepad uses the system default encoding. so it doesn't surprise me that this is happening. have you considered using a more encoding-aware editor like Notepad++ or SublimeText?

Comment: I pasted on microsoft office word with same effect. See : https://i.imgur.com/VZTXQdY.png. Besides, notepad displays the text correctly when copying from teamviewer as I said in the description.

Comment: I suggested N++ or Sublime because you can manually select the encoding type.

Comment: @FrankThomas, to be more specific this is a problem that is occuring to my users and they're used to microsoft word. Installing other editors isn't an option at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the copy on the remote machine I had to switch the keyboard layout (alt-shift), then procede to copying the text and pasting on my local machine with the correct encoding.